# SQL Reporting Services, controlling possible word wrap issue in tablecell

Tags: sql, vb.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

First of all, I am extremely new to sql reporting services, so my guess as to what is causing this issue could very well be off.

Basically, the first page of my reports spit out just fine, but when the 2nd+ pages hit, the width of the table is greater than 8.5 (which is what the interactivewidth is set to) inches because it clips off the page, and then creates a whole other page that looks blank, but if you look closely you will see the edge of the table from the previous page on the left side like so:

[image]

I suspect is might have to do with a possible word wrapping issue on this particular tablecell:

[image]

Because on the 2nd+ pages, that same tablecell displays as:

[image]

Which seems to be where the extra width is coming from that is making the table to wide for the page width. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSRS doesn't allow column width to change dynamically, so you don't have to worry about that. The settings you need to adjust are the Page Size and the Margins. If the default margin on each side is 1 inch, you are left with 6.5 inches width to really work with. Try reducing the margin first, that should fix it.

Comment: All margins of the report are 0.1 inch with the page size being 11in x 8.5in so those seem to look fine. For whatever reason the table holding all of this together is correct on the first page and then gets wider on the following pages.

Comment: EDIT: Thh 0.1 margins were in fact the issue, which you suggested.